# MySQL prefixing an entire table's columns names when using *

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT
      table_1.*,
      table_2.*
FROM 
     .....
```

Table 1 and table 2 both have the same column names:

```
ID
Value
```

What I want to do is something like

```
SELECT
      table_1.* AS 'prefix_1_'.*,
      table_2.* AS 'prefix_2_'.*
FROM 
     .....
```

So I would end up with:

```
array(prefix_1_ID = X, prefix_1_Value = X, prefix_2_ID = Y, prefix_2_Value = Y)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible to my knowledge.

Comment: You will have to list out all of the columns and add an alias for each one that matches that format.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if this were possible. Also even if it were you'd probably be better off not doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: Would be a nice feature, feel free to suggested in the mysql forum. Right now you have to type it.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate. The answer in the other question requires that I specify all of the columns that I want to append to, iterate through them, and append appropriately. This question was about 'globally' appending to all columns in `table`.`*`